# LinqToEntities use less than (<) within LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities, left-join

I'm working with a colleague and we're trying to reproduce the following SQL Query using LinqToEntities (Entity Framework v4.0)

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM [dbo].LocaleStringResource AS t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].LocaleStringResource AS t2
    ON (t1.ResourceName = t2.ResourceName AND t1.AccountId < t2.AccountId)
WHERE t2.ResourceName IS NULL;
```

Basically it's saying only return us the highest AccountIds where there is more than one matching ResourceName.  We have got this so far...

```
localeStringResource = from e1 in localeStringResource
  join e2 in localeStringResource
  on new { e1.ResourceName, e1.AccountId } equals new { e2.ResourceName, e2.AccountId }
  where e2.ResourceName == null
  select e1;
```

But we don't seem to be able to work out how to achieve the equivalent less than (<) within the LEFT OUTER JOIN?

```
ON (t1.ResourceName = t2.ResourceName AND t1.AccountId < t2.AccountId)
```

Could anyone please advise if this is possible or if we're barking up the wrong tree?  We have attempted to make the initial query as simple as possible hoping it will make the equivalent LinqToEntities query easier to build.

Note:

`AccountId` is not unique. We have an `Identity` `Id` column on the `LocalResourceString` table.  However there is a Unique Constraint on both `AccountId` and `ResourceName`

Comment: It looks like what you really want to do is select the records that have the largest `AccountId` for each `ResourceName`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<EDIT>
It looks like what you really want to do is select the records that have the largest `AccountId` for each `ResourceName`. If we assume that `AccountId` is unique, then:

```
localeStringResource =
    from e1 in localeStringResource
    group e1 by e1.ResourceName into grp
    select grp.Max(e => e.AccountID);
```

</EDIT>

You have a left outer join here, so your LINQ is going to need a `GroupJoin`-`SelectMany`-`DefaultIfEmpty` construct. `Join` and `GroupJoin` are restructed to equality, but you can add the remainder of the condition later, before the `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
localeStringResource =
    from e1 in localeStringResource
    join e2inner in localeStringResource
        on e1.ResourceName equals e2inner.ResourceName
        into grp
    from e2 in grp
        .Where(e => e1.AccountId < e.AccountId)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    where e2.ResourceName == null
    select e1;
```

Here's the method syntax, for reference. I used `Tuple` to pass the data around:

```
localeStringResource = localeStringResource
    .GroupJoin(
        localeStringResource,
        e1 => e1.ResourceName,
        e2 => e2.ResourceName,
        Tuple.Create)
    .SelectMany(pair => pair.Item2
        .Where(e2 => pair.Item1.AccountID < e2.AccountID)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        .Select( e2 => Tuple.Create(pair.Item1, e2)))
    .Where(pair => pair.Item2.ResourceName == null)
    .Select(pair => pair.Item1);
```

Comment: Thanks Thom I think your original answer may be the ticket, although as mentioned in your EDIT our AccountId's aren't unique (this is a lookup up table, I have amended the question to add more details about the fields). I am writing a test now to see what we get back.

Comment: The edit should work if the pair {`AccountId`, `ResourceName`} is unique. There could be an issue if there were multiple distinct records with the same `AccountId` and `ResourceName`, in which case the shortened query would only return one of them. It doesn't look like that is an issue here.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the ANSI-82 syntax putting the join criteria in the where clause:

```
localeStringResource = from e1 in localeStringResource
                       from e2 in localeStringResource
                       where e1.ResourceName = e2.ResourceName &&
                            e1.AccountId < e2.AccountId
                       select e1;
```

Comment: This will perform an inner join, not a left join.

Comment: Thanks Jim but we require to filter by `ResourceName == null` so we only return those rows that we have multiple values for.